# Unable to run second WebClient request after timed out and aborting request

Tags: asynchronous, webclient

I have a desktop app which is downloading 1 or more small files (jpg with less than 400KB in size and no more than 20 at a time)  simultaneously using a CustomWebClient object and calling OpenReadAsync(). The download process is working just fine if there is no problem in the process. I want to limit the response to a certain time (15 sec) so I have introduced a timeOut handling which is Aborting the request. Even the timeout is working and after that my “OpenReadCompletedEventHandler” method is receiving System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled (which is the right behaviour).
Now, my problem is that I want to allow the user to try re-loading the picture(s). So the next webClient request(s) are failing with the same WebException. Below is my code.

Here is my Custom WebClient class (used in order to have more than 2 async connections at a time):

```
internal class ExtendedWebClient : WebClient
{
    private Timer _timer;
    public int ConnectionLimit { get; set; }
    public int ConnectionTimeout { get; set; }
    public ExtendedWebClient()
    {
        this.ConnectionLimit = 2;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request != null){_timer = new Timer(TimeoutRequest, request, ConnectionTimeout, Timeout.Infinite);

            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = this.ConnectionLimit;
            request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5000;
            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 5000;
        }

        return request;
    }

    private void TimeoutRequest(object state)
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
        _timer = null;
        ((WebRequest)state).Abort();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }    
}
```

Here is the code to download the files using my custom WebClient class:

```
internal struct PageWaitHandleState
{
    public int WaitHandleIndexInPage;
    public bool ImageIsLoaded;
    public string ErrMessage;
}

public Image[] downloadedImages;

private PageWaitHandleState[] waitHandlesInPage;
private OpenReadCompletedEventHandler[] downloadComplete;
private EventWaitHandle[] pagesEWH = null;
private EventWaitHandle[] downloadImageEvent;
private int availableImages = 1;  // Set here to simplify, but as I stated in my description, it may be more than 1.
int downloadTimeOut = 15000;
int maxSimultaneousDownloads = 20;

private void DownloadImages(int pageIndex = 0, string[] imageUrl)
{
    if (pagesEWH[pageIndex] != null)
    {
        ReloadImages(pageIndex, imageUrl);  // Executed in the second request
        return;
    else
    {
        pagesEWH[pageIndex] = new EventWaitHandle[availableImages]; 
        downloadedImages = new Image[availableImages];
        downloadComplete = new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler[availableImages];
        downloadImageEvent = new EventWaitHandle[availableImages];
        waitHandlesInPage = new PageWaitHandleState[availableImages];

        // Set the downloadComplete deletages
        for (int i = 0; i < availableImages; i++)
        {
            downloadComplete[i] = ProcessImage;
        }
    }

    for (int imgCounter = 0; i < availableImages; i++)
    {
        waitHandlesInPage[imgCounter] = new PageWaitHandleState() { ImageIsLoaded = false, WaitHandleIndexInPage = imgCounter, ErrMessage = null };
        downloadImageEvent[imgCounter] = GrabImageAsync(imageUrl[imgCounter], downloadComplete[imgCounter], imgCounter, downloadTimeOut, maxSimultaneousDownloads);
        pagesEWH[imgCounter] = downloadImageEvent[imgCounter];
    }

        offenderIndex++;
    }
}

private static EventWaitHandle GrabImageAsync(string url, OpenReadCompletedEventHandler openReadCompletedEventHandler, int imgCounter, int downloadTimeOut, int maxSimultaneousDownloads)
{
    var myClient = new ExtendedWebClient();
    myClient.ConnectionLimit = maxSimultaneousDownloads;
    myClient.ConnectionTimeout = downloadTimeOut;
    myClient.OpenReadCompleted += openReadCompletedEventHandler;
    var iewh = new ImageEventWaitHandle() { ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset), ImageIndex = imgCounter };
    myClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url), iewh);
    return iewh.ewh;
}

internal void ProcessImage(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ImageEventWaitHandle iewh = (ImageEventWaitHandle)e.UserState;
    bool disposeObject = false;

    try
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            this.waitHandlesInPage[iewh.ImageIndex].ImageIsLoaded = false;
            this.waitHandlesInPage[iewh.ImageIndex].ErrMessage = "WebClient request was cancelled";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            this.waitHandlesInPage[iewh.ImageIndex].ImageIsLoaded = false;
            this.waitHandlesInPage[iewh.ImageIndex].ErrMessage = e.Error.Message;
            iewh.ewh.Set();
            this.downloadImageEvent[iewh.ImageIndex].Close();
        }
        else
        {
            using (Stream inputStream = e.Result)
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                int totalReadBytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Exception fired here with the second request
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    totalReadBytes += bytesRead;
                } while (inputStream.CanRead && bytesRead > 0); 

                this.downloadedImages[iewh.ImageIndex] = Image.FromStream(ms);
                this.waitHandlesInPage[iewh.ImageIndex].ImageIsLoaded = true;
                this.waitHandlesInPage[iewh.ImageIndex].ErrMessage = null;
            }
            disposeObject = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        this.downloadedImages[iewh.ImageIndex] = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Signal the wait handle
        if (disposeObject)
        {
            iewh.ewh.Set();
            ((WebClient)sender).Dispose();
        }
    }
}

private void ReloadImages(int pageIndex, string[] imageUrl)
{
    for (int imgCounter = 0; imgCounter < availableImages; imgCounter++)
    {
        this.downloadComplete[imgCounter] = this.ProcessImage;
        this.waitHandlesInPage[imgCounter] = new PageWaitHandleState() { ImageIsLoaded = false, WaitHandleIndexInPage = imgCounter, ErrMessage = null };
        this.downloadImageEvent[imgCounter] = GrabImageAsync(ImageUrl[imgCounter],this.downloadComplete[imgCounter], imgCounter, downloadTimeOut, maxSimultaneousDownloads);
        this.pagesEWH[imgCounter] = this.downloadImageEvent[imgCounter];
    }
}
```

Finally, when I want to access the images I check if they are ready by using:

```
private bool ImagesInPageReady(int pageIndex, int recordsInCurrentPage)
{
    if (_PagesEWH[pageIndex] != null)
    {
        int completedDownloadsCount = 0;
        bool waitHandleSet;

        // Wait for the default images first (imgCounter = 0). When moving page or asking for more pictures, then wait for the others.
        for (int ewhIndexInPage = 0; ewhIndexInPage < recordsInCurrentPage; ewhIndexInPage++)
        {
            if (this.pagesEWH[ewhIndexInPage].WaitOne(this.downloadTimeOut))
            {
                if (this.WaitHandlesInPage[ewhIndexInPage].ImageIsLoaded)
                {
                    completedDownloadsCount++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.pagesEWH[ewhIndexInPage].Set();
            }
        }

        return (completedDownloadsCount > 0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is immaterial to the question but many APIs here are obsolete. You can probably shrink the code in half using the TPL and `HttpClient` and `await`.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4, so unfortunately, I won't be able to use await. Thanks for your comment any way.

Comment: You can use await with 4.0.

Comment: May you provide me some example of how I might achieve what I want using update APIs, but with .NET 4? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: BTW, I'm familiar with HttpClient, as I use it in the same application to send and receive data to and from our asp.net webapis. But the thruth is that I found more examples for multiple concurrent downloads using WebClient than HttpClient.

Comment: I'd like to direct you to search for ".net 4.0 await". HttpClient is, I think, also available. It plays nicer with await. WebClient also works, though.

Answer (score 0):

@usr, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  HttpClient was the solution. So I basically encapsulated my HttpClient object in a new class, together with the ProcessImage() method and exposing and event fired by the same method.